# is there any server configaurations needs to change for session management

Tags: apache-flex, jsp

I have developed an application with JSP and Flex. In that Flex application interact JSP with HTTP service. I deployed application in one server that server URL is with HTTP it is working fine. But when I deployed this project in another server (HTTPS) the application is not running. There in JSP session is not handled. Is there any server configuration whicn needs to be checked?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're talking about with "session is not handled". Please elaborate the problem in developer perspective, not in enduser perspective. What exactly happens? What exactly happens not?

I can at least tell that sessions are usually backed by cookies. Cookies on its turn are usually bound to a specific domain and path. Cookies are not dependent from the protocol used. Roughly said, if the webcontainer has created a cookie to track the `HttpSession`, it will by default use the `request.getServerName()` as cookie domain and `request.getContextPath()` as cookie path.

So if you for example have this webapplication on `http://example.com/context`, then the cookie will be created for host `example.com` and path `/context`. Regardless of the protocol. But when you fire a request on `http://example.com/anothercontext`, then by default you won't get the same cookie back and thus also not the same session.

However, most webcontainers provides configuration options which can influence the cookie host and path. Tomcat, for example, supports an `emptySessionPath` attribute in the [HTTP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) which causes that the cookie path is always `/`. This way the `http://example.com/context` and `http://example.com/anothercontext` will be able to share the same cookies and thus also the session.

This knowledge of how it all works "under the hood" must give a better understanding of your problem and thus also ease nailing down of the root cause.